# Windows 10, user with different font-size rearrange other user's desktop icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, multiple-users

I have this problem with Windows 10:
I have one user with font size at 150% and other with standard dimension.

When the user with greater font-size logs on, the icon on the desktop of the other user are rearranged on a smaller area.

This happens every time the other user logon.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Windows has always been this way.

Comment: lol, so users with better eyes have to live with reduced desktop...

Comment: Even RDP does this.  The only solution is to give them different logins / desktops.  Or give them remote logins using LogMeIn or TeamViewer.